# How to make enter to indent work inside of function arguments in atom?

Tags: python, atom-editor

I installed the atom editor on mac / Linux and I got mostly everything working for Python editing except for one really annoying thing which is newline to indent in functions. I will just try to describe what i mean here, this works correctly now:

```
def my_function():
   do_something <== automatically indented when I press enter
```

However when indenting arguments within a function call or definition the behavior is wrong.

```
myfunction(args,
another_arg <=== not correctly indented should be indented to just below args.
```

What is it I need to customize in atom for this to work correctly ?